# How to do I add Collapsing Toolbar in my layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-styles, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

How to I add `CollapsingToolbarLyout` in my `header_cover_image` see the picture below The blue Highlighted one.

[image]

I tried alot of work but still I can't figure it out. I hope you can help me Thank you!

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/layout">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/header_cover_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/user_cover" />
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:clickable="true"
    app:civ_border_width="3dp"
    app:civ_border_color="#FFFFFFFF"
    android:id="@+id/profile"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/header_cover_image"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="-130dp"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/hooman" />
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/profile_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/header_cover_image"
    android:background="@color/purpleCorallite"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:paddingBottom="24dp">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btnEdit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"

        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/user_email"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/name"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Email@email.com"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
</RelativeLayout>




</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Search for tutorial instead [Here is one](https://antonioleiva.com/collapsing-toolbar-layout/) . If you find any issue after implementing then you are welcome to question here .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in style file ensure that `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">



            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/header_cover_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/user" />


            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />


        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="700dp"
            >

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/profile_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                android:paddingBottom="24dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                    android:id="@+id/profile"
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:elevation="5dp"
                    android:padding="20dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/damo"
                    app:civ_border_color="#FFFFFFFF"
                    app:civ_border_width="3dp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/name"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/btnEdit"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.818"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/profile"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="208dp"
                    android:text="Name"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:textSize="24sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/user_email"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/name"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:text="Email@email.com"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/name"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
                    android:text="put the data here"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.105"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/user_email" />


            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: I got this error `ScrollView can host only one direct child`

Comment: remove scrollview put the the profile element inside the NestedScrollView

Comment: @ShiftingArrow iupdated my answer check again..if its ok with you mark the answer as accept....

Comment: that thing works but how can I add more layout for User the user informations like
Name:
Type:
Email:
it says `ScrollView can host only one direct child`

Comment: @ShiftingArrow i updated the answer...dont forget to mark the answer if ok with you

Answer (score 0):

Add this attribute in your scrollview **android:fillViewport="true"**

```
 <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">
```

(or) if its not working refer this below example

https://inducesmile.com/android-tips/android-coordinatorlayout-and-collapsingtoolbarlayout-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

In place of scrollview you need to use CollapsingToolbarLayout under the coordinator layout in xml.

something like this -

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="@dimen/tall_toolbar_height">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleGravity="top"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap">

 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btnEdit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit" />

      <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
          app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
  </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```